# Authenticating JIRA REST API access with jsonlite::fromJSON in R?

Tags: json, r, jira

I am trying to access JIRA issue details using jsonlite library as follows in vain:

```
library(jsonlite)    
jiradata <- fromJSON("https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=DATAX AND key=DATAX-1234")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode your URL.

```
jiradata <- fromJSON(URLencode("https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=DATAX AND key=DATAX-1234"))
```

Spaces in your request may causes a HTTP error 400 if not properly encoded.

Comment: I tried using URLencode. The problem is passing on the user authentication credentials to access the info from JIRA.

Comment: @RanonKahn how are you passing the user credentials?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out on how to pass on the user credentials using jsonlite::fromJSON. Apparently, that is not possible.

Comment: @RanonKahn at this site https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html, you can find information about the REST request you should send to JIRA with how to parse properly the URL and how to set the correct header for the JIRA authentication.